# Saving an XLSM file as any file name, format, and directory

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I am looking for a macro to save a currently open XLSM file as something other than the XLSM file with the below conditions.

1. I want to be able to save the file as any name.
2. I want to be able to save the file as any format.
3. I want to be able to choose the directory where it is save.

So basically I want to be able to save the file just like I would do a normal Save As file without using a macro.

I have seen a number of different macros out there that do parts of my request but nothing with all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FileDialog :

```
Sub Example1()
Dim intChoice As Integer 
Dim strPath As String 

'make the file dialog visible to the user 
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
'determine what choice the user made 
If intChoice <> 0 Then 
    'get the file path selected by the user 
    strPath = _ 
        Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1) 
    'displays the result in a message box 
Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
End If 
End Sub
```

To use `SaveAs`, take a look : http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm and https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff841185.aspx

Comment: Works exactly like I wanted.  I just thought it would be so much more code to do it.  Thanks so much!